# What changes should be made in algorithm/ code to get expected shapes of vehicles?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, fft, issue-tracking

I am working on a project in image processing which is based on importance of phase only reconstruction. For more information you can read the answer given by geometrikal in https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/16462/how-moving-part-pixel-intensity-values-of-video-frames-becomes-dominant-compared

I want to

> Detect moving objects from the [video of traffic on road](https://signal642.shutterfly.com/pictures/8) ( Please download  the 1.47 MB video by ( step1) **click on the play button** then (step2) right clicking on video then ( step3 ) click on save as option )

Algorithm for it is

The proposed approach

Requirement: An input image sequence I(x, y, n) (where x and y are image dimensions and n represent frame number in a video) which is extracted from video.

Outcome: The segmentation mask of moving object for each frame

> 1. For each frame in a input video perform step 2, append step 2 result in resultant array ‘I(x, y, n)’
> 2. Smoothen the current frame using 2D Gaussian filter
> 3. Perform 3D FFT for the whole sequence I(x, y, n) using [(Eq.4.1)](http://it.thislife.com/exzPhP)
> 4. Calculate the phase spectrum using the real and imaginary parts of 3D DFT
> 5. Calculate the reconstructed sequence Î(x, y, n) using (Eq.4.2)
> 6. For each frame in a input video perform step 7 to step 10 to get segmentation mask for each frame and append step 10 result in resultant segmentation mask array BW(x,y,n)’
> 7. Smooth the reconstructed frame of Î(x, y, n) using the averaging filter.
> 8. Compute the mean value of the current frame
> 9. Convert the current frame into binary image using mean value as the threshold
> 10. Perform morphological processing, i.e., filling and closing, to obtain segmented mask of moving object for the current frame
> 11. End algorithm.

With the above algorithm I could find all moving object from the video.

But the problem is the vehicle segmented mask that I obtained has no proper shape which I am expecting.

[image: example moving object segmentation]

So can anybody help me for getting **expected** shape ?

> 1. What changes should I make in the algorithm?

or

> 2. What changes should I make in MATLAB code ?

```
    tic
clc;
clear all;
close all;
  
%read video file
video = VideoReader('D:\dvd\Matlab code\test videos\5.mp4');

T= video.NumberOfFrames  ;           %number of frames%

frameHeight = video.Height;          %frame height

frameWidth = video.Width ;           %frameWidth

get(video);                          %return graphics properties of video


i=1;

for t=300:15:550  %select frames between 300 to 550 with interval of 15 from the video  
    frame_x(:,:,:,i)= read(video, t); 
    frame_y=frame_x(:,:,:,i);

    %figure,
    %imshow(f1),title(['test frames :' num2str(i)]);
    frame_z=rgb2gray(frame_y);                 %convert each colour frame into gray
    
    frame_m(:,:,:,i)=frame_y; %Store colour frames in the frame_m array 
     
    %Perform Gaussian Filtering
    h1=(1/8)*(1/8)*[1 3 3 1]'*[1 3 3 1]  ;   % 4*4 Gaussian Kernel  
    convn=conv2(frame_z,h1,'same');
        
    g1=uint8(convn);
    
                    
    Filtered_Image_Array(:,:,i)=g1; %Store filtered images into an array
    i=i+1;
end

%Apply 3-D Fourier Transform on video sequences
f_transform=fftn(Filtered_Image_Array);

%Compute phase spectrum array from f_transform
phase_spectrum_array =exp(1j*angle(f_transform));

%Apply 3-D Inverse Fourier Transform on phase spectrum array and
%reconstruct the frames
reconstructed_frame_array=(ifftn(phase_spectrum_array));


k=i;

i=1;
for t=1:k-1
    
    %Smooth the reconstructed frame of Î(x, y, n) using the averaging filter.
    Reconstructed_frame_magnitude=abs(reconstructed_frame_array(:,:,t));  
    H = fspecial('disk',4);
    circular_avg(:,:,t) = imfilter(Reconstructed_frame_magnitude,H);
        
    
    %Convert the current frame into binary image using mean value as the threshold
    mean_value=mean2(circular_avg(:,:,t));  
    binary_frame = im2bw(circular_avg(:,:,t),1.6*mean_value);
    
    
    %Perform Morphological operations
    se = strel('square',3);
    morphological_closing = imclose(binary_frame,se); 
    morphological_closing=imclearborder(morphological_closing); %clear noise present at the borders of the frames
    
    
    %Superimpose segmented masks on it's respective frames to obtain moving
    %objects
    moving_object_frame = frame_m(:,:,:,i);
    moving_object_frame(morphological_closing) = 255;  
    figure,
    imshow(moving_object_frame,[]), title(['Moving objects in Frame :' num2str(i)]);
    
 i=i+1;
end
toc
```

Comment: I cannot see a save as option. Any idea?

Comment: @Hwathanie I think you have directly right clicked on video. that's why there is no option of save as.   please click on the play button first  ,then right click on video . you will see "save as" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the details of the algorithm (btw, you could gain in visibility by using more meaningful names than f1,f2,f7,mean1,mean2, etc.) but it seems that your problem is inherent to the technic used.

By using phase of FFT, you are working independently on each pixel without any kind of contour awareness. What you could do though is tuning a bit the threshold (fixed at the mean here) and see how it responds.

Another option would be to post treat the current results by trying to recognize your expected shape in the images (see maximum expectation algorithms).

What are your constraints ?

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback . yes,you are right, I have obtained the segmentation mask by doing postprocessing operation on frames which are phase only reconstructed . as you said I should tune proper threshold but can you tell me how it could me done in MATLAB ? If possible will you add code in your answer with corrections made in my code to get proper shape of vehicles ?

Comment: also ,I am not good in morphological processing. So I am unable to do filling and other morphological operations properly on the frames.

Comment: What do you mean by "how" ? changing that line `avg2 = im2bw(avg(:,:,t),1.6*meanvalue);` ? here the threshold is `1.6*meanvalue` but you can modify it.

Comment: OK I will modify my code with meaningful names also try to check the results by changing threshold values on trial and error basis.

Comment: sir, I am still not getting  expected results by changing the threshold value. its shape is still similar as previous on and not proper yet.

Comment: Ok I have just seen your other post for the question also. Since the segmentation mask process is well described, have you been given also clues on what type of algorithms you could use for the tracking in that exercise ? because general tracking is too wide and in general is a non trivial thing.

Comment: As regards with the segmentation part, maybe you could try being more aggressive if the morphological closure (the `imclose` function). (PS you have [here](http://www.dspguide.com/ch25/4.htm) some simple explain on morphological closure if you don't know it is at all)

Comment: sir, I have used $imclose$ function few days before but it didn't changed result much. Main problem here is I am not understanding how to make balance between threshold value (for algorithm step no 9 ) and morphological operator values.

Comment: also in case of my other post , I you have observed that I have detected all the moving part in the video frames. But now I want to detect only one moving object at a time from current frame **and avoid other moving objects**. that's why I said tracking of  any **single** object .

Comment: Yes I understand that's the purpose of tracking ^^. But it's not magic you have at least to initialize it (and some algorithm need even training). Initialization will learn position of the only object you take in account. That's why I asked you if you had been given any clue or advice on the type of algorithm that your teacher expects ? if not then you should ask him for clues first I think.

Comment: sorry sir, my teacher has not given any clue or advice . should I change title and data in the question of tracking ?

Comment: I'm quite new here but I think so since it's actually a tracking problem. And maybe say what you have (but not detail all segmentation steps) and what you want to do. Or maybe just edit your other post which is already nearer to your problem, and answer to the guy that advised to use a Kalman filter, he might have more details on that.